# Plot heat map with quiver on top of it

Tags: data-visualization, graphs

I am looking for a program that can plot a [heat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) with [quiver plot (aka. velocity plot)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) on top of it when given a 2D array as input. Is possible, free, Python/Java/C++/Matlab/R and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Heat map using [matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pcolor#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor):

[image]

Quiver using [matplotlib.pyplot.quiver](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) ([demo](http://matplotlib.org/_images/quiver_demo_00.png))_:

[image]

I would like to combine those two:

[image]

The arrows of the quiver would represent the variation of the values of the heat map.

Comment: What do you mean with "represent the variation of the values of the heat map"?

Answer (score 1):

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is my favorite for plotting any kind of 1D or 2D data. It is a tool without graphical user interface, but I think you like it.

```
set pm3d map
set size ratio -1
unset key
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,10
splot "data.dat" using 1:2:(sqrt($3**2+$4**2)), "" using 1:2:(0):3:4:(0) with vectors linecolor rgb "#000000"
```

[image: Contour+vector]

Of course, these are almost default settings, but with a bit of tweaking you can make it a lot nicer, and also export it directly to any kind of

I've also used the [Gnuplot-Python](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) interface, which basically works with exactly the same commands, where you can directly stream you python variables to gnuplot.

My experience with gnuplot and gnuplot-py is with various Linux-distributions only, but both claim to be available for Windows as well.